# Strange behavior of variables in different UIViewControllers

Tags: swift

I have two UIViewControllers (`Master` and `Detail` to put it simple). In my `Master Controller` I have a `tableView` with some list of objects, and I'm using `Detail Controller` to show details and to change some properties of these objects.

It seems extremely straightforward and simple.

let's suppose I have an object with such structure:

```
class User {
   var name = ""
   var lastPoints:[LastPoint] = []
 }
```

In my `Master Controller` I will show the list of users, and in my `Detail Controller` I want to be able to remove `lastPoints`.

so in `didSelectRowAt` of my `Master Controller` I have:

```
let suVC = ShowUserViewController()
suVC.currentUser = self.usersToShow[indexPath.row]
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(suVC, animated: true)
```

and after that I'm able to work with this new variable in my `Detail Controller`. For example, I can remove one of the last points in `currentUser`.

The thing is, this `lastPoint` will be immediately removed from `self.usersToShow[indexPath.row]` from `Master Controller` as well, and I need to avoid this (and also I want to understand what is the reason for this behavior: yes, it seems logical and even convenient for most cases, but I can't remember such behavior in previous projects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is Simple the array of classes is reference type so change it to

```
struct User {
   var name = ""
    var lastPoints:[LastPoint] = []
}
```

where `struct` is a value type

Comment: Of if there are other reasons to make `User` a Class object then you could copy it and pass the copy to the detail view controller.

Comment: @DuncanC yes this is  the other alternative if he has to

Comment: @Sh_Khan but i kinda DID copy it. What is the right way to copy it in this case? (your solution works, thanks, I just want to know the other way to solve it).

Comment: @lithium you need to implement **NSCopying** protocol , look to this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy ,,, also note that **LastPoint** should also implement it , the **.copy()** method appears for any object only if it's implement that protocol

Answer (score 2):

This is because User is a class, which is a **reference type** in Swift. When your detail controller gets the current user, it shares a reference to the exact same User instance as is shown in the master controller. Since it's the same User, the change to its `lastPoints` will be reflected in both places.